# Android documentation in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android

I'm trying Mono for Android in Visual Studio 2012. How can I access Android documentation right from Visual Studio (by pressing F1 for Android function name).

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can't. The only proper documentation sources are:

- http://androidapi.xamarin.com/ for the API documentation
- http://docs.xamarin.com/ for general documentation
- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html for the good old API guides from Android

It would be a nice to have feature though :-)